# Sentry: How to configure sentry in php?

Tags: php, sentry

This is for `Sentry (Open-source error tracking)` users.

I have tried some code, but I don't get success. I hope you could look into this.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

I have download the SDK zip and upload it on servers. Well, I have read from some stuff for autoloader and raven_client but still, I don't find autoloder.php.

I am using **sentry/sdk:2.0.3**

```
require_once 'sentry-php-master/src/Sdk.php';

Sentry\init(['dsn' => '___DSN___' ]);

throw new Exception("My first Sentry error!");
```

I am expecting it works and I can trace the errors.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using composer ?

Composer solves a number of problems including dependency resolution for PHP packages, keeping all packages updated and another benefit of using composer is autoloading.

I would suggest the following approach:

1. `composer require sentry/sdk:2.1.0` in your project's root directory.
2. `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`
3. Connect the SDK to Sentry

   `Sentry\init(['dsn' =>
   'https://6cxxx20aa1xxx5axx47xxxb8@sentry.io/18xxx47']);`

Lastly, verify your setup by triggering a PHP exception by throwing one as you've already done with `throw new Exception("My first Sentry error!");`

[Docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/#verifying-your-setup)

Comment: Hope this helps.